# Linked List. Confused as to equality issue in code

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```
var LinkedList = function() {
  var list = {};
  list.head = null;
  list.tail = null;

  list.addToTail = function(value) {
    var node = Node(value);
    if (list.head === null) {
      //have to equal list.tail = list.head because you want them pointing to the same object
      list.tail = list.head = Node(value);
    } else {
      list.tail.next = node;
      list.tail = node;
    }
  };
return list;
};

var Node = function(value) {
  var node = {};

  node.value = value;
  node.next = null;

  return node;
};
```

I have a bit of a simple question. I'm building a linked list and I have a particular issue with the `.addToTail` property I have built. The current code above works and executes like I want it to. Two part question. If I write my code like this for the `if/else` statements:

```
  if (list.head === null) {
    list.tail = node;
    list.head = node;
  } else {
    list.tail.next = Node(value);
    list.tail = Node(value);
  }
```

My `if` statement does not work even though I am setting `tail` and `head` to the same value separately. It only works if I have them equal to each other in one line like in the original code `list.tail = list.head = node`. I don't understand what the difference is here. They're the same values so why does writing it separately not work? Also, in my `else` statement; if I set the values of `list.tail.next` and `list.tail` to `Node(value)`. This does not work properly but replacing `Node(value)` with `var node = Node(value)` does work like in the original code.

The first block of code gives me my node list correctly:
`head: { value: 4, next: { value: 5, next: [Object] } }`. The second block of code gives me: `head: { value: 4, next: { value: 5, next: null }}` It doesn't set the `next` value property correctly for tail. What the heck is going on here? Am I missing something? These two blocks of codes should be equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do

```
    list.tail.next = Node(value);
    list.tail = Node(value);
```

you can creating two instances of Node

where

```
      list.tail.next = node;
      list.tail = node;
```

only create one

Comment: Ah... How did I miss that. That is so obvious now. Thank you! It is the same reason for both conditions.